# How to connect an UIView to my custom class

Tags: ios, swift

I connected a view which belongs to a view controller to a custom class via an `IBOutlet` declaration.

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` method I declare a variable and I use the variable to connect `myView` with the class `myClass`.

```
    var myConnectedView = myView as! myClass
```

Though, this code returns a runtime error: `Could not cast value of type 'UIView'`. I seem to find no way to assign a `UIView` to a class.

**Question**

How do I assign a `UIView` to a `UIView` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Storyboard interface you can set the class of the `UIView`. If you head over into the Utilities panel you can find an option where you can modify the class of the `UIView`.

Right now it says `UIView` (this is default). You have to set it there to `myClass` if this is a class that inherits from a `UIView`.

Right now the view is assigned to the `UIView` class.

Answer (score 2):

From the Storyboard interface go to the Utility sidebar which is to the right side of the screen. Click the third tab also known as Identity Inspector and change the class for the `UIView`. Be sure to click the view object to edit its respective class (in your case, `myClass`).

[image]